# Deactivate locale for unicode characters

Tags: ios, swift

When I go to the playground and I write `let test = "\u{062F}\u{0625} Hello"`, I get `Hello دإ` (which by the way when I copy from the output console to here I get `دإ Hello`)

It seems there is an automatic locale thing (tell me if I'm wrong).

My question is how to deactivate it so that I have `Hello دإ` when I println(test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the UI doing the right thing. Specifically Cocoa knows how to handle BIDI or Bidirectional text. Web sites do not normally. 
In a Bidirectional string, it lays out starting with first language order then lays the next language substring range in line but in its language ordering. 
RTL Rifght to Left or LTR left to right. Vertical adds complexity that isn't so simple yet. The playground UI knows what to do because it is AppKit

Comment: So there is no way to deactivate it?

Comment: Not unless you control the application. So if you build an app, you can set the RTL/LTR for your textfields, or more globally set the locale of the app, though on iOS, you may need the user to set their locale if your app is localized. you might try changing the order of the characters in the string. Or use an NSAttributedString and set the attributes in the playground. A plain string doesn't know much, so the playground logs it however the playground logs it. If you think it's wrong, file a bug with apple.

Comment: okay thanks. And don't really need to file a bug. I'll trust apple on this one ;)